# Should I aggregate? Is this a sensible approach?

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I've got a web app that tracks page views. The app checks the IP address of the end-user and maps it to a Country. Everything works here so far.

However, I am realizing that this table (called `views`) is getting populated very fast, since it tracks every page view. On some pages reaching 500k, 1M, etc. Which could potentially store over millions of records on this table within a short time.

I thought about aggregating the results every 24 hours into a new table (called `country_views`) and then deleting the records in `views`.

So for example. My `views` table could look like:

```
page_id | country_id | created_at | updated_at
======= | ========== |=========== | ==========
1       | 1          | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
1       | 2          | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
1       | 1          | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
1       | 1          | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
2       | 4          | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
2       | 3          | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
```

After 24 hours. I count the results from this table and put them into a new table called `country_views`. Which could look like:

```
page_id | country_id | total | created_at | updated_at
======= | ========== | ===== | ========== | ==========
1       | 1          | 3     | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
1       | 2          | 1     | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
2       | 4          | 1     | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
2       | 3          | 1     | 2011-11... | 2011-11...
```

On the same web app. I plan on showing this data to certain users as a pie chart to display which countries are viewing certain pages.

Is this a sensible approach? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: it makes sence, though your data have a lot of duplicates. As I understand, a page is created only once, but viewed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just keep a count in views?

You only want to count which page was viewed by which country so just add a count column and increment it if the record already exists otherwise add a new row :)

Comment: However, what if I want to keep track of how many views were viewed in a day as well. Having a `count` column won't provide me with that data set

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is fine, especially since it could be easily programatically undone.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know if it can be undone, since the results from the `views` table will be deleted for good

Comment: I meant that you could easily recreate the original data using the aggregated data you're storing.